# How to remove the need of a CD when there is a need for multiple no of CD's to be played

Tags: audio, compact-disc

I am having 9 audio CD's to be used

The first CD has the software to run the remaining 8 Cd's.The CD1 has an audio file and its exercise continues to the next CD i.e CD2 and so on it continues to CD8.

There are no of issues handling multiple CD's

1. Its time consuming to remove 1 Cd after another.
2. Requires care while removing it from the packet and placing in the
       optical drive.
3. Possibility of misplacing the CD.

So how can I avoid this cumbersome process and also remove the need of a CD if possible.Also would it make a difference with the type of data stored i.e an audio file,video file,etc.

I am looking for a possible solution which is compatible with Windows 10.

Tried the ripping software below and got an error just at the end of the disk.
[image: Saving could not completed.Could not read from disc.(Sector235480)]

Output format:Mp3

BitRate:192Kbps

Comment: How the files are saved in the cds, i.e their format(mp3,wma etc)? Are they comman formats?

Comment: If so, open each audio file in [Audacity](http://audacityteam.org/), click *save as* from *File* and save them into your HDD or any other storage.

Comment: @RogUE its in .cda file.IS this an error with the CD or some software issue

Comment: Have you tried opening it with Audacity? I do not know much about it technically, but I have done it(Used a different software-Virtual DJ), and I got the file from the cd.

Answer (score 1):

Install a CD ripper software (like [this](http://www.ashampoo.com/dl/0710/ashampoo_burningstudio6_free_sm.exe) one), and rip the contents of every one of the 9 CD's (select Burn or Rip music --> Rip audio CD). The program will then copy the audio and you can then move the files to a USB key.

Comment: Got an error while ripping the content.Check the update

Comment: That just means the program couldn't read from the CD, most probably because of some physical problem, a scratch for example. Can you confirm the scratch?

Comment: No scratches because its a brand new CD removed from the seal.Also viewed the CD slant in front of light.It's plain no scratches

Comment: Have you tried it again? Some problems just happen on the first time. You can also try to rip it on different PC.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you need the program off the first CD to use the software properly.  If all you need is the audio files, try to copy them directly off the disc if they are a common format, like .mp3, .ogg, etc.  You will need to right-click and select "Open..." on the disc to view its files and copy them.

You can convert a CD to an .iso file using a program like [Imgburn](http://www.imgburn.com/) - if you already have CD burning software installed, it may have a function like "Create an image" or similar.  Make sure your program can do .iso files and not some proprietary format (like Nero's .nrg).

Then look into programs that create "virtual" CD drives - you can basically point the software to an .iso file on your system, and the software will make it look like a CD-ROM (DVD-ROM, etc.) to the OS.  I've had success with the free [Virtual Clone Drive](http://www.slysoft.com/en/virtual-clonedrive.html) in the past.  It may take a bit of disk space to have nine .iso's on your system, but it will be more convenient than switching physical CDs.

Comment: At first when double clicked the CD2 to play it gave me a pop-up saying there's no software associated with it.Later I simply right click/Explore.From here i chose open with an select windows media player to play the tracks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I used the ashampo Cd ripper and could rip 7 out of 9 CD's successfully only the 2 Cd's (CD2 and CD6) had the above Could not burn disc problem.The output generated is mp3 files due to which I can now play anywhere even on Mobile and without software like iso mount.So once I get to know this sector problem It will resolve all my problems +give portable to listen